# Controlling plot range of histogram

Tags: plotting, histograms

I tried the following code:

```
data = {2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 13, 14, 14, 
   14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24,
    25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 28, 29, 31, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 43, 44, 44, 
   44, 51, 51, 52, 55, 55, 57, 57, 58, 59, 60, 60, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64,
    68, 68, 72, 73, 74, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, 79, 80, 80, 81, 83, 84, 
   85, 87, 88, 88, 90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 95, 96, 97, 97, 98};

Histogram[data, {1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{30, 58}, All}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

It produces a bar for 29 at left outside of the defined plot range:

[image]

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Histogram` does not process the `PlotRange` option.  It just passes it on to the generated `Graphics` expression.  `PlotRange` in `Histogram` does not affect how the histogram is computed.

If you want to restrict the domain over which the histogram is computed, use a custom binning specification.  Instead of `{1}`, use `{30, 58, 1}`.

If you simply want to clip things outside of the frame, use `PlotRangeClipping -> True`.  This does not affect what the `Graphics` expression contains.  It only affects what is drawn on screen.  Like `PlotRange` this is also a `Graphics` option that `Histogram` will simply pass on without processing it.